# PHP - Laravel take last row of table

Tags: php, laravel

I want to take last row of table using orderby.
**Results:**

```
{"anime":[{"id":25,"title":"Black Clover","epnumber":14},
{"id":25,"title":"Black Clover","epnumber":13},
{"id":25,"title":"Black Clover","epnumber":12},
{"id":25,"title":"Black Clover","epnumber":11},
{"id":25,"title":"Black Clover","epnumber":10},
{"id":26,"title":"One Piece","epnumber":200},
{"id":26,"title":"One Piece","epnumber":199}]}
```

**But I actually want is.**

```
{"anime":[{"id":25,"title":"Black Clover","epnumber":14}{"id":26,"title":"One Piece","epnumber":200}]}
```

**My code:**

```
$anime = DB::table('seasons')->orderBy('episodes.epnumber', 'desc')
->join('animes','animes.id','seasons.animes_id')
->join('episodes','episodes.seasons_id','seasons.id')
->get(['animes.id', 'animes.title', 'episodes.epnumber'])->toArray();
```

Comment: you can include a limit clause, or else simply take the first entry of returned array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just group the data and get the MAX episode number:

```
$anime = DB::table('seasons')->orderBy('episodes.epnumber', 'desc')
->join('animes','animes.id','seasons.animes_id')
->join('episodes','episodes.seasons_id','seasons.id')
->groupBy('animes.id', 'animes.title')
->get(['animes.id', 'animes.title', \DB::raw('MAX(episodes.epnumber) as epnumber')])->toArray();
```

Comment: Yeah, I solved my problem. Thanks. And I need to use "as" thats all. \DB::raw('MAX(episodes.dugaar) as epnumber')

Answer (score 1):

you can use (take()) function:

```
$anime = DB::table('seasons')->orderBy('episodes.epnumber', 'desc')
->join('animes','animes.id','seasons.animes_id')
->join('episodes','episodes.seasons_id','seasons.id')
->get(['animes.id', 'animes.title', 'episodes.epnumber'])->take(1)->toArray();
```

or just the first:

```
$anime = DB::table('seasons')->orderBy('episodes.epnumber', 'desc')
->join('animes','animes.id','seasons.animes_id')
->join('episodes','episodes.seasons_id','seasons.id')->select(['animes.id', 'animes.title', 'episodes.epnumber'])->first();
```

Comment: If I use first() or take(1). It will show only one data.